# What was Palestine/Israel called originally?

Tags: history

In the Quran there is no Palestine but I noticed Israel is mentioned.

What exactly was the original or oldest name known of Palestine/Israel?

I'm not talking about the Philistine (Roman name given), I'm talking about much OLDER name or the first name of that land.

Comment: What is the relevance to Islam in this question? Israel is not quoted in the qur'an as a reference to a region rather than to a prophet.

Comment: Note: "Israel" mentioned in the Qur'an refers to the name of the Prophet Yaqub عليه السلام

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this would be a better fit on history SE

Comment: I agree that the question would better fit on history SE. As a rule, should questions that may be transferred be answered or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Israel is the given name of the forefather of the people of Israel. It is the name of the people, not of the region. The name of the land in the time of Mose was  Canaan, the south was called Moab. It seems that these names were also linked to the people living there.
Land and people have different names in Jewish and Greek sources.

Comment: I'm not so familiar with what's written in the quran, but in the Torah tradition, Canaan and Moab are the names of individuals who founded their eponymous nations. And the lands where they lived were named after them.

Comment: the Torah also never refers to the land as Israel. It's only after the division of the Israelite kingdom into two kingdoms that one of them was named Israel.

Comment: That's actually what I am trying to say in my answer.

Comment: More precise answer of the usings of the Word Israel in the Quran: Children of Israel (the people) 41 times, the Prophet Israel: 2 times, the land Israel: never.

Comment: @Daniel this is not really correct. The Five Books of Moses do not refer to the Land as Israel because Israel did not live in it yet. But in the rest of Tanach, it is sometimes referred to as the "Land of Israel" separate from the Kingdom of Israel (although the most common appellation is just "the Land"). E.g. 1 Samuel 13:19; Ezekiel 40:2, 47:21.